# Game of Life (GoL) in 3D cellular automaton and its rule numbers

Tags: symbolic, cellular-automata, nks

I walked through [How to calculate CellularAutomaton rule numbers in higher dimensions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153388/how-to-calculate-cellularautomaton-rule-numbers-in-higher-dimensions) to produce the following code for the [Advent of Code, day 17](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/17), which asks for "Life, but in 3D". More concretely:

- an active cell with exactly 2 or 3 live neighbours in its 27-cell neighbourhood stays active, otherwise dies;
- an inactive cell with exactly 3 live neighbours becomes active, otherwise stays dead.

The code performs one time-step of the automaton, starting with a 2D slice of the space configured as a Life glider, and everything else zero.

```
 With[{d = 3}, 
   CellularAutomaton[<|
     "OuterTotalisticCode" -> 
      Total[d^(d #[[2]] + #[[1]]) & /@ {{0, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}}], 
     "Dimension" -> d, "Colors" -> 2, 
     "Neighborhood" -> 
      "Moore"|>, {{{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}}, 0}, {1, All}]]
```

Running the code, however, it becomes clear that it is total nonsense.

What has this code actually done?

A check for correctness is that after one timestep, we have evolved the initial slice forward by one space in 2D Life, so we should see a glider step in the central slice. What was actually produced is… definitely not that.

[image: evolution]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You should probably also [**CHECK HERE**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202852/13) "my answer", which explains the enumeration schema for CAs.  It is pretty simple for outer totalistic rules. In 2D you can define GoL and test it on a glider:

```
GoL2D=<|"OuterTotalisticCode"->224,"Dimension"->2,"Neighborhood"->9|>;
ArrayPlot[#,ImageSize->40,Mesh->True]&/@
CellularAutomaton[GoL2D,{{{0,1,0},{0,0,1},{1,1,1}},0},8]
```

[image]

Where is 224 rule number is coming? Well, - from special ordering of outer totalistic rule table. After running

```
RulePlot@CellularAutomaton[GoL2D]
```

[image]

where arrows show the order of how to read out binary code (black 1, white 0) so you easily get 224 by running:

```
FromDigits[
{0,0,0,
0,0,0,
0,0,0,
0,1,1,
1,0,0,
0,0,0},2]
```

> 224

This is equivalent to

```
Flatten[Table[{{1,k}->If[k==2||k==3,1,0],{0,k}->If[k==3,1,0]},{k,8,0,-1}],1]
%//Values//FromDigits[#,2]&
```

> {{1,8}->0,{0,8}->0,{1,7}->0,{0,7}->0,{1,6}->0,{0,6}->0,{1,5}->0,{0,5}->0,{1,4}->0,{0,4}->0,{1,3}->1,{0,3}->1,{1,2}->1,{0,2}->0,{1,1}->0,{0,1}->0,{1,0}->0,{0,0}->0}

> 224

where the 1st number in the `Key` is value of central cell, and 2nd number is value of sum of outer neighbors. This is easily generalizable to 3D, which gives same rule number:

```
Flatten[Table[{{1,k}->If[k==2||k==3,1,0],{0,k}->If[k==3,1,0]},{k,26,0,-1}],1]
%//Values//FromDigits[#,2]&
```

> {{1,26}->0,{0,26}->0,{1,25}->0,{0,25}->0,{1,24}->0,{0,24}->0,{1,23}->0,{0,23}->0,{1,22}->0,{0,22}->0,{1,21}->0,{0,21}->0,{1,20}->0,{0,20}->0,{1,19}->0,{0,19}->0,{1,18}->0,{0,18}->0,{1,17}->0,{0,17}->0,{1,16}->0,{0,16}->0,{1,15}->0,{0,15}->0,{1,14}->0,{0,14}->0,{1,13}->0,{0,13}->0,{1,12}->0,{0,12}->0,{1,11}->0,{0,11}->0,{1,10}->0,{0,10}->0,{1,9}->0,{0,9}->0,{1,8}->0,{0,8}->0,{1,7}->0,{0,7}->0,{1,6}->0,{0,6}->0,{1,5}->0,{0,5}->0,{1,4}->0,{0,4}->0,{1,3}->1,{0,3}->1,{1,2}->1,{0,2}->0,{1,1}->0,{0,1}->0,{1,0}->0,{0,0}->0}

> 224

The rule number is the same in this specific case as generalization to higher dimension adds only **zeros on the left** into binary code for the rule number. Here this rule's CA starts from random cube 9x9x9 embedded in empty field:

```
GoL3D=<|"OuterTotalisticCode"->224,"Dimension"->3,"Neighborhood"->27|>;
Image3D[#,ColorFunction->"WhiteBlackOpacity"]&/@
CellularAutomaton[GoL3D,{RandomInteger[1,{3,3,3}],0},7]
```

[image]

Here is a way to test on some simple manual initial conditions by crafting 9x9 cube and seeing how values die according to the right real GoL rules. Here just 3 live cells will make fireworks you see at the top:

```
ini={Table[0,3,3],{{1,0,0},{0,1,1},{0,0,0}},Table[0,3,3]};
Image3D[ini,ColorFunction->"WhiteBlackOpacity"]

anim=Image3D[#,ColorFunction->"WhiteBlackOpacity"]&/@
CellularAutomaton[GoL3D,{ini,0},30];

Export["anim.gif",anim,AnimationRepetitions->Infinity,ImageSize->400]
```

Comment: I don't understand why the rule number 224 stayed the same despite the number of dimensions going up by 1. Per https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202852/30771, the rule number should depend on the dimension. Why has it not done so here?

Comment: @PatrickStevens Because in this specific case higher dimensions just added zeros on the left of binary number, which does not change anything. Here is a toy example: `FromDigits[{0,1,1,1,0},2]==FromDigits[{0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0},2]` gives `True`.